# Is $f(x,y)=\frac{xy^2}{x^2 + y^2}$ with $f(0,0)=0$ continuous at $(0,0)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases}  \dfrac{xy^2}{x^2 + y^2} & \text{ if } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\   0 & \text{ if } (x,y) = (0,0)\end{cases} $$

(i) Is $f$ continuous at $(0,0)$?

At $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ this function is continuous, but we needed to check if it is at $(x,y) = (0,0)$. I said:

$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{r^3\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)}{r^2(1)} = 0$$

However folks in an IRC said I couldn't use polar coordinates or spherical coordinates and that this was wrong. I don't understand why though.

Comment: @Shobhit Your link does not address my question.

Comment: Of course you can use polar coordinates. What you wrote is not quite a proof, because $\theta$ may vary with $(x,y)$ (but your line simply mentioning the limit makes it appear as if $\theta$ is kept fixed, and hides this issue), but it is almost a proof: $|r\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)|\le r\to0$ if $(x,y)\to(0,0)$, so we have the result.

Comment: @Ozera his link DID answer your question.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I think their argument was that it depended on \theta and saying only $r \to 0$ was wrong.

Comment: @Jossie Ah, I see it now.

Comment: Well, if $(x,y)\to(0,0)$, then $r\to0$, and regardless of $\theta$, the expression you wrote is bounded above in absolute value by $r$, which is independent of $\theta$. As I said, what you wrote does not quite suffice, but the conclusion is correct, and to fix what you wrote is simply to point out the obvious inequality I mentioned.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/155626/68107 (Just to get mathSE to form a link)

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546721/proving-that-fx-y-fracxy2x2-y2-is-a-continuous-function-using-ep and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422778/showing-that-lim-x-y-to-0-0-fracxy2x2y2-0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try to be more elaborate on the point I was trying to get across on the IRC earlier today.

Let's consider the following function, defined in the polar coordinates: $f: [0, \infty) \times (0, 2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$, 
$$
f(r, \theta) = \frac{r}{\theta}
$$
This is well defined, because our angle argument, $\theta$, varies in $(0, 2\pi]$, and not in $[0, 2\pi)$ as usual. Obviously this does not matter at all, because $2\pi$ determines the same angle as $0$. This function determines a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ in a natural way, and I will denote that function by $f$ as well, using $x, y$ coordinates instead of $r, \theta$, hoping that will not cause any confusion. Also, $f(0) = 0$ (because the point $(0, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is represented in polar coordinates as $(0, \theta)$ for any choice of $\theta$, and $f(0, \theta) = \frac{0}{\theta} = 0$).

So, what's the limit: 
$$
\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, y) = \;?
$$

Let's try to solve it using your approach:
$$
\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, y) = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{r}{\theta} = 0
$$

Easy, wasn't it? And the resulting value does not depend on $\theta$. Let's conclude thus that the limit is $0$ and call it a day.

Right? Wrong! Consider a sequence (in polar coordinates):
$$
x_n = \left(r_n, \theta_n\right) = \left(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{\pi}{n}\right)
$$
Basically, we start with $x_1$ which is $(-1, 0)$ in cartesian coordinates, and we go clockwise, approaching half a turn, and going closer and closer to $(0, 0)$ in process. It's obvious that as a sequence of point in a plane, this sequence tends to $(0, 0)$ (because, well, in cartesian coordinates it's $x_n = (r_n \cos \theta_n, r_n \sin \theta_n) = (\frac{1}{n} \cos(\frac{\pi}{n}), \frac{1}{n} \sin(\frac{\pi}{n}))$, and obviously each component tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$).

Now, if $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, y)$ was in fact $0$, then we would also have $\lim f(x_n) = 0$, because $x_n \to (0, 0)$. But, surprisingly:
$$
\lim f(x_n) = \lim f(r_n, \theta_n) = \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{\pi}{n}} = \frac{1}{\pi} \ne 0
$$

What happened? It turns out, that $\lim_{r \to 0} f(r, \theta) = 0$ does *not* imply that $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, y) = 0$. When we consider the limit as $r \to 0$, we keep $\theta$ fixed, so we only take a limit along a single straight line passing through the origin. This only implies that if we restrict the our function to any such straight line $L$, and consider a function $f|_L: L \to \mathbb{R}$ it *will* in fact be continuous at $0$. The problem is that the fact that the restricted function $f|_L: L \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at origin for every $L$ passing through origin, it's not enough to conclude that our function is in fact continuous at origin.