# Is there an $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ function with the following (limit) property?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Is there an $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ function which does not have a limit at a point $a$ ($\nexists \lim\limits_{a} f$), but we get the same value as a possible value for the limit when we try to approach $f(a)$ through any line?

I think we would need $$f to not be differentiable around $a$. In that case, it would not be approximated by a linear function, so it could have a different limit with a non-linear path. However, I can't go further. And I don't even know if it's a goof approach.

This is not a homework, it was just mentioned by my calculus teacher in the previous semester.

Comment: See [Is f(x,y)=xy2x2+y2 with f(0,0)=0 continuous at (0,0) ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507204/is-fx-y-fracxy2x2-y2-with-f0-0-0-continuous-at-0-0).

Comment: On the line $X=0$ define it as $0$, on the line $Y=mX$ define it as $m(X^2+Y^2)$. Then along the sequence $(1/m^2,1/m)$ it goes to infinity.

Comment: Since $f$ is not continuous at $a$ it cannot be differentiable there.

Comment: @user539887 I think that's what I wanted, thank you!

Comment: @totoro Thanks, it looks good as well.

Comment: @copper.hat I know that, but it can be differentiable on $R^2$ \ $\{a\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, let $A = \{(r \cos t , r \sin t) | t \in (0,2 \pi] , 0 \le r  \le t\}$.

Define $f = 1_A$, then $f$ does not have a limit as $x \to 0$ but has the limit $1$
along each line through the origin.

Comment: It might be obvious, but how can you see that it does not have limit at $0$?

Comment: (It is easiest to see if you draw a picture of $A$.) If we let $x_n={2 \over n} (\cos {1 \over n}, \sin {1 \over n})$ then since $x_n \notin A$ we have $f(x_n) = 0$ and $x_n \to 0$. However with $y_n={1 \over n} (\cos {1 \over n}, \sin {1 \over n})$ we have $f(y_n) = 1$, and $y_n \to 0$. Hence $f$ cannot have a limit at $0$.

Comment: However, along each line through the origin, there is a small interval containing $0$ in its interior) on which $f$ is $1$, hence it has the limit $1$ along any path to $0$ (on the line).

Comment: It's possibly simpler to let $P=\{(x,x^2): x\in \mathbb R\}$ and $f= \chi_P.$

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. Do you know any good software to draw a picture of A?

Comment: @zhw. has a simpler answer.

Comment: @zhw. What's $\chi_P$?

Comment: Another notation for the indicator function.

Comment: I like the shape of $A$, sort of a Pac-Man with under bite.

Comment: For @zhw. 's function, is it good to check it with the $x_n=\frac{1}{n}(\cos(t), \sin(t))$, for a fixed $t$, observe that $\cos(t)^2 \neq \sin(t)$, so $f(x_n) \to 0$, but for $x_n=(1/n, 1/n^2)$, $f(x_n) \to 1$?