# Limit of $f(x, y)$ at $(0, 0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I need to show 
$$\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} = 0
$$
Not really sure how to go about this without using the epsilon delta definition, which I would prefer not to. Any sort of help is appreciated.

Edit: I do have the inequality:

$$\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} \le \frac{xy(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} = \frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)} $$

Comment: Check the final line I think you made a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use polar coordinates: by letting $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$, we have that
$$\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}= \frac{r^4\sin(2\theta)\cos(2\theta)}{2r^3}=\frac{r\sin(4\theta)}{4}.$$
Therefore
$$\left|\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\right|\leq \frac{r}{4}$$
and the right-hand side goes to $0$ as $r\to 0$.

P.S. Your equality is too "weak" for the job: by taking $y=x$ the right-hand side is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks, are using polar coordinates quite a common approach to solving such limits? Haven't encountered their use before

Comment: Yes, it is. You can find more examples in this site. For example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297618/calculating-lim-x-y-to0-0-fracx2yx2y4

Answer (score 6):

Let $(x,y) \not =(0,0)$.

$0\le |\dfrac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}| \le \dfrac{|xy||x^2+y^2|}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} $

$\le \dfrac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}= (x^2+y^2)^{1/2}.$

Used:

1)$|x^2-y^2| \le |x^2+y^2|;$

2)$x^2+y^2 \ge |xy|$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=tx$. Then

$$\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{x^2tx^2(1-t^2)}{x^3(1+t^2)^{3/2}}=x\frac{t(1-t^2)}{(1+t^2)^{3/2}}.$$

As the fraction remains bounded for all values of $t$, the limit is $0$.

Comment: I think this is not true, because the existsence and equality of the limits along all of the lines through the origin won't imply the existence of the original limit. (See, for example, my old question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741516/is-there-an-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr-function-with-the-following-limit-pr )

Comment: @Botond: I never spoke about a limit along all lines in the sense of constant $t$. $(x,y)$ and $(x,t)$ are equivalent 2D representations, as $t$ spans all of $\mathbb R$. Feel free to retract your downvote.

Comment: I see. I thought that you fixed $t$. But I did not downvote your answer, so I can't retract it, just give you an upvote :) (I prefer to not upvote and ask for clarification over downvote, especially in the case of smarter people's answers)

Comment: @Botond: sorry for suspecting you :-)