# Proving that $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$ with $ f(0,0)=0$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \dfrac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\Leftrightarrow x^2+y^2\not=0\\0\Leftrightarrow x=y=0\end{cases}$$

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Do you have tools available to you like L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: $$   2 |xy| \leq x^2 + y^2 $$

Comment: @user2566092 how do you use L'Hopitals rule for a function of two variables?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155623/proving-that-the-function-fracx2yx2-y2-is-continuous-at-0-0
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262874/show-that-gx-y-fracx2y2xy-is-continuous-at-0-0
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507204/is-fx-y-fracxy2x2-y2-continuous-at-0-0
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546721/proving-that-fx-y-fracxy2x2-y2-is-a-continuous-function-using-ep
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422778/showing-that-lim-x-y-to-0-0-fracxy2x2y2-0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving that the function $\frac{x^2y}{x^2 + y^2}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155623/proving-that-the-function-fracx2yx2-y2-is-continuous-at-0-0)

Comment: @Jack When editing posts, please keep in mind [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9687). Specifically, \dfrac, \displaystyle are not good in the titles. Neither is  `\begin{cases} .. \end{cases}` (at least if it can be avoided).

Answer (score 2):

If $x\neq 0$ we have
$$\left|\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right|=\frac{|y|}{1+\displaystyle\frac{y^2}{x^2}}\leq |y|$$
So, for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ we have $0\leq |f(x,y)|\leq|y|$. It follows from the squeeze theorem that
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=0=f(0,0)$$
and thus $f$ is continuous at origin.

If $a\neq 0$ or $b\neq 0$, it follows from basic properties of limits that
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}f(x,y)=f(a,b)$$
and thus $f$ is also continuous at any point $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is evidently continuous out of the origin. We will inspect the origin.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Take $\delta:=\epsilon$

If $\vert \textbf{x} \vert < \delta$, then $|y| < \delta$ (where $\textbf{x}=(x,y)$). Therefore:

$\displaystyle |f(x,y)| =\frac{|x^2y|}{|x^2+y^2|}< |y|<\epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

The function is continuous at $(0,0)$ because $\|\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\|_2=\|\frac{x^2y+y^3-y^3\|}{\|(x,y)\|_2^2}\leq\|(0,y)\|+ \|\frac{(0,y^3)\|}{\|(x,y)\|^2}\leq \|(x,y)\|+\frac{\|(x,y)\|_2^3}{\|(x,y)\|_2^2}=2\|(x,y)\|_2$ and the rest is corollary.