# Continuity but not differentiability of $f(x,y)= \frac{xy^2}{x^2 + y^2}$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Define $f(x,y) = 0$ if $(x,y) = (0,0)$ and $f(x,y) = \dfrac{x y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$.
>
> a) Show that $f$ is continuous at the origin.
>
> b) Prove $(D_uf)(x)$ exists at $(0,0)$ for any direction $\vec{u}$.
>
> c) Show $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

No ideas about any of them. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried to use the limit definition of the directional derivative for $\hat{u} = (a,b)$ at $\vec{x} = (0,0)$? $$(\mathcal{D}_{\hat{u}} f)(x, y) \ = \ \lim_{h \to 0} \ \dfrac{f(x + ah, y+bh)-f(x,y)}{h}$$ Note that $f(x,y) = 0$ if $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

Comment: a) introduce polar coordinates. b) set $y=kx$ and derivate c) necessary condition for differentiability: the directional derivatives in b) must be equal.

Comment: See [Proving that $f(x,y) = \frac{xy^2}{x^2 + y^2}$ is a continuous function using epsilon-delta.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546721/proving-that-fx-y-fracxy2x2-y2-is-a-continuous-function-using-ep) and [Showing that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0, 0)}\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2} = 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422778/showing-that-lim-x-y-to-0-0-fracxy2x2y2-0) for the first part.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the $f: R^2 \to R$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$ iff $f$ can be expressed in the form $f(x,y) = f(a,b) + f_x(a,b)(x-a)+f_y(a,b)(y-b) + E(x,y)$ with the error term $E(x,y)$ satisfies: $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b)} \dfrac{E(x,y)}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}}=0$. Thus you either prove the partials does not exist or the limit of $E$ is not zero. Let's find out what really happens to $f$. We have: $f_x(0,0) = \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(h+0,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} = \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{0-0}{h}= 0=\displaystyle \lim_{k \to 0} \dfrac{f(0,0+k)-f(0,0)}{k} = \displaystyle \lim_{k \to 0} \dfrac{0-0}{k} = 0$. Since $f(0,0) = 0$, we have $E(x,y) = f(x,y) = \dfrac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$. Thus: $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{E(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = \text{ does not exist }$. All that you need to prove it does not exist is to choose $2$ paths for example: $(x,y) = (t,t)$, and $(x,y) = (2t,t)$

Comment: you forgot the square root at euclidean norm :)

Comment: why can we have the first condition you give which means it is differentiable?

Comment: @Matthew: The condition is part of the definition of differentiability of $f$ at $(a,b)$ in addition to $f_x(a,b), f_y(a,b)$ exist. This condition means that there is a tangent plane to the graph of $z = f(x,y)$ at the point $(a,b,f(a,b))$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

(a) $\dfrac1{x^2 + y^2} \le \dfrac1{y^2}$ for $y\ne 0$.

(b) $f(hu_1, hu_2) = h \dfrac{u_1u_2^2}{u_1^2 + u_2^2}$ for $h\ne 0, u\ne 0$.

(c) Is $D_u f(0)$ linear in $u$?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $f:\mathbb R^{2}\to \mathbb R$ is differentiable at $\vec x=(x,y)$ then for all $\epsilon >0$, there is a $\delta_{\epsilon } >0$ such that

$$\tag 1 \vert f(\vec x+\vec h)-f(\vec x)\vert -\nabla f(\vec x)\cdot \vec h\vert <\epsilon \vec \vert h\vert $$ whenever $\vert \vec h\vert <\delta_{\epsilon } $.

Set $\vec x =0$. Then, we have $f(\vec 0)=0$, and $\nabla f(\vec 0)=0$ so $(1)$ becomes $$\tag 2 \left | \frac{f(\vec h)}{\vec h} \right |<\epsilon$$ which amounts to, upon setting $\vec h=(h,k)$, $$\tag 4\left |  \dfrac{hk^2}{\left ( h^2+k^2 \right )^{3/2}} \right |<\epsilon$$

Now if we take $h=k$, $(4)$ becomes $\frac{k^{3}}{2\sqrt 2k^{3}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}$ so that as soon as $\epsilon < \frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}$, there is no $\delta $ that will satisfy $(2)$ and we have a contradiction.