# Showing that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0, 0)}\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2} = 0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Show that
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0, 0)}\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2} = 0$$

I have tried switching to polar coordinates but I'm not getting a single term. 
This is what I did.

Putting
$$x=r\sin θ,\quad  y=r\cos θ$$
we obtain

$$\left|\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|=|r\cos^2 θ \sin θ|
                       =|r\sin θ(1-\sin^2 θ)|
                       = |r\sin θ-r\sin^3 θ|$$

Comment: Look in [that question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492288/is-there-limit-lim-x-y-to-0-0-fracx3x2-y2?rq=1).

Comment: "I have tried switching to polar coordinates but I'm not getting a single term." Please show your try in this direction.

Comment: You have $r$ times something which is of absolute value less than 1. Since $r$ goes to zero as you approach the origin, your expression does too.

Answer (score 3):

Using the change of variables
$$\begin{align*}x &= \rho\cos\theta\\
y &= \rho\sin\theta
\end{align*}$$

we obtain
$$\lim_{\rho \to 0} \rho\cos\theta\sin^2\theta = 0,$$
since $\cos\theta$ and $\sin^2\theta$ are bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ then if $\delta = \epsilon$ we have whenever $|x|<\delta$ and $|y|<\delta$ that

${|xy^2| \over x^2 + y2} <= {|x|(x^2+y^2)\over x^2+y^2} = |x| < \delta = \epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

$|x| \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $|y| \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. So what is the absolute value of your expression in question? In general don't try switching to polar coordinates if the expression will not simplify.