# How to find $\lim \dfrac{4xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

My book uses epsilon to solve this and the answer should be zero but I'd like another easier way

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{4xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$$

Comment: How about polar coordinates?

Comment: @Jack Exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: See also [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422778/showing-that-lim-x-y-to-0-0-fracxy2x2y2-0) and other questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1422778).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $x=r \sin \theta$ and $y=r \cos \theta$.

$$\lim_{r \to 0} 4 r^3 \cos \theta \sin^2 \theta=0 $$

Comment: Does this method work always whenever i come across similar examples or just under certain conditions?

Comment: @Square-root It always works however sometimes it's more useful than others.

Comment: @Square-root Like now.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $ 0 \leq \left|\dfrac{4xy^2}{x^2+y^2}\right| \leq |4x|$

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $x^2+y^2\geqslant 2xy$ for any choice of $x,y$, so that $$\left|\frac{4xy^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leqslant \left|\frac{4xy^2}{2xy}\right| = |2y|$$